# sql server(Find the difference between 2 columns in 2 rows )

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having a problem with a Cashback Report I am building. Here is the code of my Stored Procedure and what i want.

```
--SP CODE
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[CashbackPromo]
    @startDate DateTime,
    @endDate DateTime
    AS
    create table #CashbackInfo
    (
     UserID int,
     PreviousBal money,
     DepositAmount money,
     NewBalance money,
     LostMoney money
    );
    --DECLARE @startDate DateTime ='2014-06-07 00:00:00'
    --DECLARE @endDate DateTime ='2014-06-08 00:00:00';
    WITH Deposits
    AS
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM CurrencyTransactions where timestamp between @startDate and @endDate and transactionType=1
    ),
    Withdrawl
    AS
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM Withdrawals where timestampRequested between @startDate and @endDate
    ),
    WithoutWithdrawals
    AS
    (
    SELECT b.userID,w.userID as uID from Deposits as b LEFT JOIN Withdrawl as w on w.userID=b.userID 
    WHERE ISNULL(w.userID,0) = 0
    ),
    DepositDetails
    AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM CurrencyTransactions where userID in(SELECT userID from WithoutWithdrawals) and transactionType=1 and timestamp between @startDate and @endDate 
    )
    --DELETE FROM #CashBackInfo
    INSERT INTO #CashbackInfo(UserID,PreviousBal,DepositAmount,NewBalance,LostMoney)
    (SELECT UserID,(newBalance-deltaRupees),deltaRupees,newBalance,0 FROM DepositDetails);
    SELECT * FROM #CashbackInfo Order By UserID
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @blueFeet for editing I am a newbie in this site, And don't know how to format code

Comment: What does `previous` and `next` mean in this context? You need a unique `ORDER BY` clause to define the order.

Comment: I am ordering by UserID it means that if user has more than one entries then we'll consider him otherwise we will be disqualified and we can sort out single entry users with RowNumber() over partition by userID .

Comment: You understand that only ordering by UserId means that "New balance of the first row" can be 528.17 the first time you run the query and  695.37 on the second?

Comment: I don't know it. Can you throw me a solution please? I am a newbie in this field and I have very little knowledge

Comment: `SELECT NewBalance - LEAD(PrevoiusBal, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY ???)` will give you the difference between two rows but since even you don't know which row is first I can't give more help.

Comment: you should add the timestamp data into the query to aid the order by and then you would know which deposit came first.

Comment: I used this code to update my lostMoney column ordered by timestamp but it is throwing me an error that subquery returned more than 1 value                                                           UPDATE #CashbackInfo SET LostMoney=(SELECT NewBalance - LEAD(PreviousBal, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY UserId ORDER BY DepositTimestamp) From #CashbackInfo)